# How to let GRUB Menu let me choose Ubuntu, Windows 10, or Windows 8.1 without the Windows Boot Manager?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have a laptop with Windows 10, Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 18.04 installed. The [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html)  menu shows the options of Ubuntu, Windows, and set up.

I can open Ubuntu from this [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) menu directly. If I want to open Windows 10 or Windows 8.1, I must choose windows from the GRUB meniu and wait for the Windows Boot Manager (that shows Windows 10 and Windows 8.1), to open to select my OS choice.

Can somebody guide me to do the necessary to make all the three operating systems appear in the GRUB menu?

Comment: This is not something GRUB can do (at least not easily), since Windows Boot Manager handles Windows boot process.